# Ritz combination principle

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, atomic-physics

The next is a translation from the [German WP](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balmer-Serie):

> Rydberg's equation describes the hydrogen spectrum quite accurately. For most other atoms, however, it does not give correct results. An advance in the description of atomic spectra was made in 1908 by the Swiss mathematician Walter Ritz. He discovered the Ritz combination principle named after him:

> By additive or subtractive combination, be it of the series formulas themselves, be it of the constants entering them, other series formulas can be formed.
> Simplified this means that from two known lines a possible third line can be calculated.

> However, not all of these calculated lines can be observed. Ritz could not explain which lines really occur.

I wonder if arbitrary wavelengths can be calculated with the Ritz combination principle? Obviously, there are in any case wavelengths which do not occur.

There are three statements in the quote above:

1. the Rydberg formula accurately describes the states of hydrogen, subsuming the Balmer series as well as the other series.
2. by additive and subtractive combinations further values can be calculated.
3. the selection of combinations does not follow any obvious principle. There are no predictions about the combinations that give meaningful results.

Is the principle then such at all?

Comment: It behooves you to specify exactly and illustrate the principle. Surely you are not asking for a tutorial on something to flesh out three vague paragraphs?  [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rydberg–Ritz_combination_principle).

Comment: @CosmasZachos I‘ve added some explanation

Comment: The [Jastrow review/explanation](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.73.60) might be helpful.